# как убрать левую панель в Midnight Commander

Tags: ubuntu, mc

как убрать левую панель в `Midnight Commander`?

Comment: не уверен, что такое есть - https://www.midnight-commander.org/wiki/ru/doc/filePanels/hotkeys

Comment: А в самом меню панели пункта нет `on/off`?

Comment: Нет такой функции, чтобы полностью панель убрать. А Вам, если не секрет, это для чего, для удобства?

Answer (score 2):

В `Midnight Commander` нет такой функцииональной возможности.

Answer (score 0):

В меню MC по F9:
 1. "Левая панель" или "Правая панель"
 2. "Формат списка"
 3. "Расширенный"